# Powershell moving files but backup the files before replacing

Tags: powershell, copy, backup, move, powershell-3.0

I have three directories:
1. RFC
2. Source
3. Backup

RFC contains files and folders(that contain files) that I need to replace in the source folder but before I replace/move files I need to backup the files I'm replacing from source to the backup folder.

I have wrote the following code, which compares RFC and Source and copies the files to backup, but it doesn't copy sub directories. I want it to move files within the sub directories as well with the same folder structure as Source. And once the copy of the files is done. I want to move files from RFC to Source.

Please any help would be highly appreciated.

```
$source = "C:\Scripts\Source\"
$backup = "C:\Scripts\Destination\"
$rfc_dir = "C:\Scripts\RFC000001234\"

$folder1Files=  dir $source
$folder2Files=  dir $rfc_dir

compare-object $folder1Files $folder2Files -property name -includeEqual -excludeDifferent | ForEach-object {
copy-item "$source\$($_.name)" -Destination "$backup" -Force -recurse
}
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

TL;DR -- the script

```
$RFC_Folder = 'c:\scripts\rfc'
$SOURCE_Folder = 'c:\scripts\source'
$BACKUP_Folder = 'c:\scripts\backup'

$rfc = get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $RFC_Folder
$source = get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $SOURCE_Folder

compare-Object -DifferenceObject $rfc -ReferenceObject $source -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -Property Name -PassThru | foreach-Object {
    # copy SOURCE to BACKUP
    $backup_dest = $_.DirectoryName -replace [regex]::Escape($SOURCE_Folder),$BACKUP_Folder
    # create directory, including intermediate paths, if necessary
    if ((test-Path -Path $backup_dest) -eq $false) { new-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $backup_dest | out-Null}
    copy-Item -Force -Path $_.FullName -Destination $backup_dest

    #copy RFC to SOURCE
    $rfc_path = $_.fullname -replace [regex]::Escape($SOURCE_Folder),$RFC_Folder
    copy-Item -Force -Path $rfc_path -Destination $_.FullName
    }
```

The explanation:

Given the OPs comment below on `ROBOCOPY` not being preferable I've updated the answer.

Your posted script is basically on the right track, however instead of using just `$backup` you have to get a little fancy with the `-Destination` parameter.  You don't want the `-Destination` to be the static path `c:\scripts\backup` you want it to update based on where the source file actually was.  For example if the file was in `c:\scripts\source\subdir1\subdir2`, you'd want `-Destination` to be `c:\scripts\backup\subdir1\subdir2`.

`$_.FullName` will be the path to the `$SOURCE_Folder` as it was used as the `-ReferenceObject`.  It's getting manipulated stringwise to create the desired RFC and Backup paths.  The `[regex]::Escape` static method is being used because the `-replace` operator does a regular expression operation on the strings, and several characters in paths need to be escaped (the slash, mainly).  All it's doing is turning `c:\scripts\source` into a regular expression escaped version: `c:\\scripts\\source`

The `if` construct is used because `copy-Item` doesn't create intermediate directories, but `new-Item` does.

Depending on your specifics this might work as is, but you may have to alter it.  For example if somehow a directory can end up in RFC that wasn't in SOURCE, this wouldn't catch that.  It also won't catch any empty directories that are in SOURCE and RFC, if that's important.

---

It may be that PowerShell isn't the best tool for this job, depending on some other factors.  As I understand it you have `Source`, `RFC` and `Backup` folders.  The `RFC` folder will contain changes that need to be committed to `Source`, but before you do that you want to backup `Source` to `Backup`.  If the folder structures are all similar between them, then perhaps the command line tool `ROBOCOPY` could do what you need?

If some of my assumptions are correct you'd first mirror the `Source` folder with the `Backup` folder.  This would contain the pre-changed files.  Then you would mirror the `RFC` folder to `Source`, this would commit any changed files/folders from `RFC` to the `Source` folder.  An example (this is a batch file):

```
REM Mirror the Source folder to Backup
ROBOCOPY C:\Scripts\Source C:\Scripts\Backup /MIR

REM Mirror the RFC folder to Source
ROBOCOPY C:\Scripts\RFC C:\Scripts\Source /MIR
```

At the end of all this your `Source` folder would be an exact replica of whatever the `RFC` folder looked like.  If `RFC` isn't a full copy of `Source`, but rather a partial copy, then you wouldn't want to use the mirror switch, `/MIR`, as it would destroy anything in `Source` that wasn't in `RFC`.

Browse around `ROBOCOPY /?` for some of its other switches, it's got a few interesting ones for logging if you want to build in some auditing capability.  Also, make extra sure to test this in a test environment.  Misuse of ROBOCOPY with a /MIR switch might make you a very sad camper.

Comment: Thank for you reply. But I don't want to back up the entire source directory. I only want to back up the files the files I'm going to replace. Source directory can have hundreds of files, backing them up will be time consuming for what I'm doing. For that reason, I only want to copy the files that I will be replacing and those files are in the RFC folder. So basically I want to match the content of RFC and Source directory and than backup files that are matched from source directory. I hope that makes it any clear.

Comment: I get errors with using the `-File` parameter (lines 5 and 6) and the `-Path` parameter (line 12) when using this with my own folders (empty backup folder, some files in source and a smaller subset in the RFC folder). Does this require some other modules? Specifically, `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'.` and `Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.`

Comment: Is it possible to write the same script as a batch file which do not require powershell?

Comment: This powershell script really does what it's supposed to do: copy folder over existing file system while moving replaced files to backup location.